# Bullhorn API Query job order by dateadded

Tags: rest

I was in process of getting API query but having an issue with Dateadded fields. I tried several combinations of date format to work but none of them any records. Some of them even not throwing error, just showing ZERO record.

Here are few examples:
Url: https://rest41.bullhornstaffing.com/rest-services/XXXXX/search/JobOrder?&start=0&fields=id,title,address,specialties(*)&BhRestToken=XXXX&query=isOpen:true AND

Condition#1:

dateAdded:['1546873357727' TO '1546534749010']

Condition#2:
dateAdded>={1546873357727} AND dateAdded<={1546534749010}

Conditions#3: 
dateAdded:"[1546873357727  TO  1546534749010]"
Condition:#4:
dateAdded>1544418000000 AND dateAdded<= 1544418000000

And above conditions with different DateTime Format.

Any other filtration like by Category, Speciality, etc working as per expected.

Appreciate a quick around time.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a "search" call instead of a "query" call you will be using the Lucene indexes which use a date format instead of milliseconds.

You need to use a yyyyMMdd format.

Here is an example form the Lucene tutorial: (http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html)

> mod_date:[20020101 TO 20030101]